# Python class takes no argument, 3 given (using __init__)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm trying to create a web crawler from youtube tutorials and such.

I'm facing an issue where I have a class that won't take arguments(other classes do take parameters, structured more or less the same)

The class (crawler.py). I'm using `__init__`, where I take 3 arguments.

```
class Crawler:
    # class variables are shared among all crawler instances
    project_name = ''
    home_url = ''
    site_domain = ''
    # use set to speed up read/write process
    file_queue = ''
    queue = set()
    # use set to speed up read/write process
    file_crawled = ''
    crawled = set()

    def __init__(self, project_name, home_url, site_domain):
        Crawler.project_name = project_name
        Crawler.home_url = home_url
        Crawler.site_domain = site_domain
        Crawler.file_queue = Crawler.project_name + '/links_on_queue.txt'
        Crawler.file_crawled = Crawler.project_name + '/links_crawled.txt'
        self.starter(Crawler.site_domain)
        self.crawl_page('first_crawler', Crawler.home_url)
```

Where it's being called, on the last line (main.py)

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
# import from files
from crawler import Crawler
from domain_finder import *
from general_crawler_functions import *

# like multiple group members doing different parts, the program
# creates multiple thread that works simultaneously

PROJECT_NAME = 'Demoblaze'
HOME_URL = 'https://www.demoblaze.com/'
DOMAIN_NAME = get_domain(HOME_URL)
FILE_QUEUE = PROJECT_NAME + '/links_on_queue.txt'
FILE_CRAWLED = PROJECT_NAME + '/links_crawled.txt'
THREAD_COUNT = 4
# queue of threads
queue = Queue()
Crawler(PROJECT_NAME, HOME_URL, DOMAIN_NAME)
```

The error said the class takes no arguments, 3 given

I'm using PyCharm Community on windows, if it helps

Comment: `Crawler.project_name = ` => `self.project_name = `, and same for the others

Comment: And please indent the class Crawler LIKE in your actual code

Comment: is the indentation in the code the same as here? it looks off

Comment: My bad with the indentation, happens when it's pasted here

Comment: Are you sure that `Crawler` isn't overwritten/shadowed by one (or both) of your star-imports? `from general_crawler_functions import *` especially sounds like it could contain it.

Answer (score 0):

In main.py you have imported Crawler from crawler

```
from crawler import Crawler
```

You should import the Crawler which you have implemented on your own.
Use

```
import Crawler
```

instead of

```
Crawler from crawler
```